# Want to center div with ion-label inside, but latter width is 100%

Tags: html, css, ionic3, centering

I'm doing an Ionic 3 application, but I'm running into a problem while styling it. The specific HTML code is this:

```
<div class="use-conditions">
    <ion-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="acceptUseConditions"></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label text-wrap class="checkbox-label">Want to center this text and the checkbox</ion-label>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" ion-button round type="submit">ENTER</button>
```

By default, "use-conditions" `div` width is this:
[image]

It fills all the space horizontally (it has the same width as the inner `ion-label`). And, if I try to apply this CSS to "use-conditions" `div`:

```
.use-conditions {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%
}
```

it its temporary centered (good!):

[image]

But, if I expand horizontally the window, it loses its centered position:
[image]

So, I think that setting width to 50% isn't good. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex box which would be responsive.

Get rid of margin-auto and width: 50%, then wrap both the button and .use-conditions in a div and give it these styles.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to better illustrate how flex box is used for these situations.
https://jsfiddle.net/q8pyjsvn/42/

Here is a great place to get you started with  flex box.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

You can centre it by making the `use-conditions` div `inline-block` and it's parent `text-align:center`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.use-conditions {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="use-conditions">
  <ion-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="acceptUseConditions"></ion-checkbox>
  <ion-label text-wrap class="checkbox-label">Want to center this text and the checkbox</ion-label>
</div><br>
<button class="submit-button" ion-button round type="submit">ENTER</button>
```

Or you could just add text align center to the use conditions div